# Infinite series involving $\cosh$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if someone knows if the following infinite series admits a closed form solution:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{[a\,\cosh(\alpha\,n)+b\,\cosh(\beta\,n)]^2-1}}
$$

with $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$ and $a,b>1$.

Thanks in advance for your help!